# "Refreshing" windows registry after key changed

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

Case:

1. Registry key has a DWORD value of 0
2. Change registry key value to 1
3. Read the value again: it is still 0

Program has to be restarted in order to read the new value.

I wad googling around and looking at the CRegKey class but I see nothing that would answer my question. I also know that explorer.exe for example has to be restarted when registry changes are made for them to take effect.

Is there any way to get a fresh "copy" of registry at run-time?

EDIT: It turns out my case above is completely incorrect. It was a bug somewhere else preventing me to read the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THere is a function: RegFlushKey()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724867%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

maybe this is what your are looking for, but this function should be called by the code that modifies registry

here is an excerpt from remarks:

> Calling RegFlushKey is an expensive operation that significantly
>   affects system-wide performance as it consumes disk bandwidth and
>   blocks modifications to all keys by all processes in the registry hive
>   that is being flushed until the flush operation completes. RegFlushKey
>   should only be called explicitly when an application must guarantee
>   that registry changes are persisted to disk immediately after
>   modification. All modifications made to keys are visible to other
>   processes without the need to flush them to disk.

Comment: I actually tried this. `RegFlushKey(reg);` before I close the regkey but it does not seem to work. It's as if the registry presented to each program is a snapshot in time at the start of the program. I'll check the return value just in case..

Comment: I recommend you use procmon from sysinternals to check changes your program does in registry, this might show whats wrong.

Comment: It turns out my question is incorrect. The case actually works completely fine, it was a bug in my code that was messing me up.. I am still going to accept your answer because it helped me nevertheless. As for RegFlushKey, I could not get it to work with reg.m_hKey or HKEY(reg) where reg is CRegKey. It returns error code #6 `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`, it does work by sending a root key as parameter tho (like HKEY_CURRENT_USER).

Answer (score 0):

<del>If the program only reads the registry on startup, then that's what it does. If it's your program, then you need to change it to re-read the registry key every time it does the relevant thing, or poll the registry at intervals to check if the value has changed. Otherwise you're going to be restarting the program.</del>

<del>Or, as is all too often the case, if you're writing the registry directly instead of calling the correct API to change a setting, *don't do that!*</del>

Edit: oops, way to misread the question there, although the above is relevant to cases like Explorer that you mentioned.

If the program is re-reading an open HKEY there may be a caching issue preventing it seeing a different program's changes. It shouldn't matter if the 'canonical' registry is in RAM or flushed to disk - that's more of a persistance issue.